# Updating state of a timer with an interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started to learn React and in the frontpage examples, it is shown how to make a simple timer component:

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { seconds: 0 };
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      seconds: prevState.seconds + 1
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Seconds: {this.state.seconds}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, mountNode);
```

Everything is pretty clear, except this line (componentDidMount method):

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
```

Why can't I directly write:

```
this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.setState is not a function
```

Comment: You might want to read up about Javascript arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Just change `tick() {` to `tick = () => {`, should work.

Answer (score 1):

In your `constructor` method you have to bind the context to `tick` method:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { seconds: 0 };
  this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Event Handling in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Answer (score 0):

Below you have a working example with the simplified version you wanted. You need to have

```
this.tick.bind(this)
```

```js
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { seconds: 0 };
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      seconds: prevState.seconds + 1
    }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Seconds: {this.state.seconds}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Timer />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```